# Jenkins Rspec tests complaining about pending migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, jenkins

I'm attempting to setup a Jenkins automated job to run my Rspec tests before doing a deploy. The goal is to run the test suite on remote server without the runtime databases.

I'm using the rake plugin and have the following commands, (keep in mind these are both prepended by rake automatically)

```
db:test:prepare RAILS_ENV=test

ci:setup:rspec spec RAILS_ENV=test
```

This works fine in one of my projects, but the other complains about pending migrations. My job output is as follows,

```
[Dev portal-admin tests] $ /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rake db:test:prepare RAILS_ENV=test
[Dev portal-admin tests] $ /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rake ci:setup:rspec spec RAILS_ENV=test
rm -rf spec/reports
Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
You have 16 pending migrations:
  20131219204223 DeviseCreateUsers
  20131219205648 DeviseInvitableAddToUsers
  etc
```

As far as I understand, `db:test:prepare` should load the database scheme from the `scheme.rb`, so I should be good with migrations. I also don't understand why it complains AFTER I get to the Rspec step, instead of the first test:prepare step.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your first rake task, `db:test:prepare`, loaded the database from your existing `schema.rb` file without objection, as it has no requirement on the migrations being current.

I suspect your subsequent `ci:setup:rspec` rake task has a dependency on `test:prepare` which has a dependency on `db:abort_if_pending_migrations`, which caused the abort you see.

For Rails 4, at least, see `activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake` in your gems directory for details of these rake task definitions.

Comment: I don't have a development database on the test machine. Do you need a development database to run tests?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I've narrowed this down to a ci_reporter issue, not a Rails one, so I've created an issue in there issue tracker, https://github.com/nicksieger/ci_reporter/issues/116.